# The syntax highligher for this js script seems to have a bug for the code after the */

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

[Regarding this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49122/script-to-read-videos-and-output-information), seems all stuff after the `/*` was grey-ed, with or without finding the matching `*/`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird case. The syntax highlighter determines what language is in use by checking the tags on the question, but [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bash) is set to use the `bsh` syntax highlighting and [shell-script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script) uses the `sh` highlighting. When there's a conflict it falls back on just detecting the language based on the code, and it's wrongly detecting it as C (we don't control this, it's part of [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/))

I'm not sure what the difference is between the `bsh` and `sh` syntax highlighting, so I don't want to change the tag assignments, but I fixed the question and answer to use `sh` highlighting